# Bizarre behavior of std::is_invocable

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer, type-traits

I have an issue with std::is_invocable in the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

void g() {}

template<bool B, typename T>
void f(T t) {
    if constexpr (B)
        g(t);
}

int main() {
    std::cerr << std::boolalpha <<
        std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&f<true, int>), int> << std::endl;
}
```

I would have expected the program output to be *false* since f<true, int> cannot be instantiated. However, GCC (as of 10.0.1 20200224) does not compile with the error message being

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of 'void f(T) [with bool B = true; T = int]':
test.cpp:14:51:   required from here
test.cpp:9:10: error: too many arguments to function 'void g()'
    9 |         g(t);
      |         ~^~~
test.cpp:4:6: note: declared here
    4 | void g() {}
      |
```

and Clang (as of 11.0.0) even prints *true*.

What is the correct behavior in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Question boils down to: does `decltype(&f<true, int>)` actually instantiate `f<true, int>`?

If yes, then the program is ill-formed because that instantiation is ill-formed (can't invoke `g` with an `int`, as requested).

If no, then the correct answer for `invocable_v` is `true` - since there is no SFINAE on the body of a function, and the signature of the function clearly allows this invocation.

It appears that gcc thinks yes (and hard errors) and clang thinks no (and yields `true`). I think clang is correct here. The rules we have are:

[[temp.inst]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#10):

> If a function template or a member function template specialization is used in a way that involves overload resolution, a declaration of the specialization is implicitly instantiated ([temp.over]).

[[temp.inst]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#11):

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member class, a static data member of a class template, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement ([stmt.if]), unless such instantiation is required.

We do involve overload resolution here (address of function), but this is just about instantiating the *declaration* of the function template. I don't think anything requires instantiating the *definition* of the function template (`f` returns `void`, not something like `auto`), so gcc is instantiating it too eagerly here.

That said, certainly it should not yield `false`.